# Javascript multi level dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav-menu">   
<li id="no" onmouseover="dropDown()" onmouseout="reverseDropDown()">
    <a href="#" >Birds</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="no2" ><a href="#" onmouseover="dropDown2()" onmouseout="reverseDropDown2()">Ratites</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Ratites</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fowl</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Neoaves</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Fowl</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Neoaves</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="no" onmouseover="dropDown()" onmouseout="reverseDropDown()">
    <a href="#">Dogs</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Big</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noizy</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS code:

```
a {
    color: #06c;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
}
li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;
}

.submenu{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:70px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: none;

}
```

Javascript code:

```
 function dropDown() {
var submenu = document.getElementById('no').getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];



    submenu.style.display="block";

}


function reverseDropDown(){

  var submenu = document.getElementById('no').getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
    submenu.style.display="none";
}

 function dropDown2() {
    var submenu = document.getElementById('no2').getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0];



        submenu.style.display="block";

    }

function reverseDropDown2(){

  var submenu = document.getElementById('no2').getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0];
    submenu.style.display="none";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmd7h0r/33/

I want to make a multi level dropdown menu using javascript ( without libraries such as jquery and without the use of css hover propery, etc).

I have tried in many ways, this is the last one and I can't get it to work. Can someone help me with explanations and/or a tutorial. Cause I did google for one and couldn't find anything except for menus using pure CSS or JQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: ...why don't you want to use CSS hover?

Comment: Your Fiddle works in Firefox? What MORE are you wanting it to do?

Comment: @JoeSwindell It doesn't work correctly. For example if you move the mouse on the second link `Dogs` it won't show the proper submenu. And troubles with the submenu as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of: You should really use event handlers. Separating logic from code (moving all js into an external file).

i've modified it a bit to reflect a possibility (changed HTML, JS, CSS):

full code here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BananaAcid/wkmd7h0r/32/)

Most important was, to stop triggering the parent A-tags: putting the onclick function on the link, not it's parent li.

```
function dropDown(a) {
    var li = a.parentElement,
        submenu = li.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

    submenu.style.display = submenu.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";

    return false;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you return `false` ?

Comment: to stop triggering the default behaviour of the link, making it ignore the content of "href". actually onclick must return `false` - i just pass it on.